# The type 'UnityEngine.Vector2' must be convertible to 'System.IComparable<UnityEngine.Vector2>' to use it as parameter 'T' in generic class Graph<T>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, icomparable

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYlgL.png)

I don't understand, How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running into an issue with [constraints on generic type parameters in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).

You are trying to create a `Graph<Vector2>`, but `Graph<T>` can only be used with generic types that implement the `IComparable<T>` interface. This is probably because the implementation of `Graph` uses `<` or `>` to compare the value of two nodes of the graph.